# Incorrect decimal value

Tags: c#, mysql

I encountered a weird situation when I insert some data inside a `DECIMAL(4,3)` column, in particular the value I'm trying to insert is: `80.018` but I'll get: `9.999` after execute this code:

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO test (capacity) VALUES (@capacity)";
 MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConnection);
 MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@capacity", 80.018);
 MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

why happen this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`decimal(4,3)` means there are total 4 digits which 3 are decimal points.
If the values are limited to `99.999` then `decimal(5,3)` will be okay.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I need to review some things, it's been a long time since I use mysql

Comment: You can; You will;

Answer (score 3):

the decimal (4,3) means you have 4 digits in total, 3 after decimal point. 80.018 require (5,3)

Answer (score 1):

For out-of-range and overflow conditions, MySQL stores the highest value allowed in the column (or lowest value allowed, if we're going negative) unless strict mode is enabled, then MySQL would throw an error.

The behavior is documented in MySQL Reference Manual here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

> When MySQL stores a value in a numeric column that is outside the permissible range of the column data type, the result depends on the SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, MySQL rejects the out-of-range value with an error, and the insert fails, in accordance with the SQL standard.
> - If no restrictive modes are enabled, MySQL clips the value to the appropriate endpoint of the column data type range and stores the resulting value instead.